# What are some good software QA community websites?

Tags: culture

The SE sites specifically are about building a repository of information and *not* about community building or discussion.  For those of us who want to build community as well as information, what are good software QA sites with a more social bent (e.g., forums and social networking style sites)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SQAForums** is the largest, and excellent:
http://www.sqaforums.com

**Software Testing Club** is excellent, too:
http://www.softwaretestingclub.com/

You'll find me hanging out at both.  (Not sure if that will scare you away or not..)

Comment: I thought I recognized you, Joe, from SQAForums...

In any case, note below that I add my vote for SQAForums.  A great place to hang and get good input and advice.

Comment: No Joe, it does not scare any of us :)

Comment: What's testrepublic.com? That site seems to not load, with a messed up page header and no content on the page.

Comment: testrepublic.com doesn't load properly for me at all. 

Also, SQAForums seems rather dead. :(

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check out [SQAForums](http://www.sqaforums.com/).  That's a pretty good community of testers there from all different skill levels as well as a few groups that are dedicated to specific tools.  Another good site is [Software Test Professionals](http://www.softwaretestpro.com/) in that they also sponsor conferences and other such things.  Both are sites I've had much experience with and have been well satisfied with that experience.

Comment: I know that SQAForums are good, but the site's design is terrible. I usually can't -find- answers there, or having hard time just browsing it for new discussions

Comment: It's a matter of finding the right forum... there are different forums for different topics... and it's more of a conversational setup rather than a Q and A setup.  StackExchange here is for the quick "Q&A" while SQA Forums is probably best for discussions and longer conversations about topics.

Answer (score 2):

[Software Testing Club](http://softwaretestingclub.com) is particularly good in my opinion.  Rosie Sherry, Rob Lambert and others have done an impressive job of building the community, and encouraging thoughtful conversations and polite debates on the site.

In addition, in my opinion, the overall level of conversation is significantly higher than the vast majority of other online software testing communities (I'm thinking of LinkedIn Groups in particular here).

I would describe the overall tone of the site / participants in the community as:

- Polite
- Well informed
- Thoughtful (e.g., people taking the time to read and understand other testers' points of views, not simply trying to "talk over them")

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend the Software Testing Club: http://www.softwaretestingclub.com/

They have active forums (actively moderated too to keep the spam/rubbish level down!), as well as publishing The Testing Planet, and sponsoring testing community activities - testing meetups, sponsoring an active member to attend a conference, etc.  The management team are really committed to creating  great community resources.  I find the level of discussion there generally high.

I've been participating there for several years now and consider it home. :)

Answer (score 2):

The Ministry of Testing has a growing following:

### https://www.ministryoftesting.com/

Also in every major tech dev city such as Boston, NY, London, San Fran, check

### https://www.meetup.com/

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm *very* bias (Director of Community at Applause) but this question is just too spot on to pass on answering.

In December we relaunched [uTest.com](http://uTest.com) to become the, "LinkedIn of Testing". In doing so we've created a professional community of 200k+ software testers where members can learn, network, share and/or find paid projects, which sounds like it aligns with what you're looking for

Best,
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective to the communities already mentioned in other answers I would recommend https://testhuddle.com/ for providing:

- Upcoming events (Webinaars/Conferences/Meets)
- Discussions and Blogs
- eBooks

Answer (score 0):

I would like to invite you to my Question and Answer site. I am a test automation engineer with 7+ years of experience. Here is my forum URL

[Software Testing Board](https://softwaretestingboard.com/qna/?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=answer&utm_content=best_software_testing_forum_answer)

About the site:
[Software Testing Board](https://softwaretestingboard.com/qna/?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=answer&utm_content=best_software_testing_forum_answer) is the open forum for all. Mayur Shah, founder, and contributor of this forum was finding it difficult to handle the questions asked by anonymous followers. So, inspired he started this site. He entertains questions related to Test Automation, Selenium WebDriver, Java, JUnit, TestNG, SOAP, JMeter and anything related to Software QA and testing. Also, he encourages visitors and registered members to answer questions asked on this site.

Comment: Edited the links. The new link is https://softwaretestingboard.com/qna/?utm_source=stackexchange&utm_medium=comment&utm_content=best_software_testing_forum_answer